# Recommended Design Pattern

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

Is there a recommended and customized design patter to follow in order to create a SharePoint 2013 Solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of design patterns to follow, depending on what you try to accomplish. For SharePoint there is a [UX design for apps in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179934.aspx) stating...

> As a developer, you should always give high priority to the user experience (UX) when you are creating apps. The model for apps for SharePoint offers many UX components and mechanisms that help you build a great user experience. The user experience in the app model is also flexible enough to let you use the techniques and platforms that best adapt to the needs of end users.

Also you need to decide whether or not to use apps or solutions following the guide in the article [Deciding between apps for SharePoint and SharePoint solutions (article)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn268593.aspx):

> Your decision to create an app versus a SharePoint solution will be determined by two things: first, the capabilities of each customization type, and second, the actual scenario you are trying to solve.

If you need more specific information on User Experience I can recommend browsing the questions in our sister site [UX.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).